# Given a group $G$ and $N\unlhd G$ with $|N| = 3$ which is not contained in the center of $G$. Show that $G$ contains a subgroup $H$ with $[G:H] = 2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups, automorphism-group

My problem is the following:

> Given a group $G$ and a normal subgroup $N$ with $|N| = 3$ which is not contained in the center of $G$. Show that $G$ contains a subgroup $H$ with $[G:H] = 2$.

**Attempted Solution:** We simply leverage the NC Theorem to obtain the desired subgroup. By the assumptions on our subgroup $N$, we have that
$$N_G(N) / C_G(N) = G / C_G(N) \le Aut(N)$$
and since $|N| = 3 \Rightarrow N \cong \mathbb{Z}_3$, which further gives us that $Aut(N) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$. Combining these results, we have that $G / C_G(N) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ and since $C_G(N) \lhd G$, we have the desired subgroup.

Comment: You should highlight where you are using that $N$ is not contained in the center: to conclude that $N_G(N)/C_G(N)=G/C_G(N)$ is not trivial, and thus the quotient must be isomorphic to the cyclic group of order $2$.

Comment: Gotcha, yes I glossed over that in the above formalism. Thanks!